# Executing multiple native queries in one go

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, native

I'm wondering if it is possible to execute several semicolon-separated SQL update queries with one `SQLQuery#executeUpdate()` call in Hibernate (3.2).

I have string containing multiple updates like this:

```
String statements = "UPDATE Foo SET bar=1*30.00 WHERE baz=1; 
                     UPDATE Foo SET bar=2*45.50 WHERE baz=2;...";
```

I'm trying to do

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery(statements);
 query.executeUpdate();
```

But keep getting the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'UPDATE Foo SET bar=Y WHERE ' at line 3
```

If I execute the contents of the `statements` by hand I get no errors so I'm assuming the multiple semicolon-separated queries are causing trouble somewhere in Hibernate or JDBC.

Is it better to just split the `statements`string and do `createSQLQuery(statement).executeUpdate()` individually for each line?

Comment: The example code was a bit off, in reality I'm calculating some amounts to bar, they should be OK without quotes, right?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to use a CASE statement. For example:

```
UPDATE Foo
    SET bar = 
    CASE baz
       WHEN 1 THEN 'X'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'Y'
    END CASE
WHERE baz in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use batch  statements, basically before you execute your query call the `addBatch(string query);` method, then when all your queries are in the batch just call the `executeBatch()` method. That will perform them all for you in the order you added the mto the batch.

also: the error in your syntax is you need put in quotes `'Y'` or `'X'`

Comment: `addBatch()` and `executeBatch` are from `java.sql.Statement`, but the poster uses Hibernate.

Comment: If I understand correctly, he referred to JDBC as a probable cause of the problem (for example, the thrown exception belongs to the JDBC connector), not as if he would accept a solution in JDBC. Janne could clear it out if JDBC is acceptable.

Comment: Nicolae is right, this isn't really the answer I am looking for. I still want to use Hibernate's SQLQuery

Comment: @Janne, im sorry I guess I didn't read the question as well as I thought, but still if you are using JDBC this is a good solution so I will not remove it because, others could learn from it. Plus it's a viable solution.

Comment: @Janne I was looking at the HIBERNATE api, and there is something very similar to what I had suggested(batch) 

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/Batcher.html#addToBatch(org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectation)

Comment: @RMT, Thanks for the pointer to the Batcher interface. Unfortunately I don't have the time to verify that it works right now as I already went the way of splitting the statements into individual strings for my original problem. When I have time I'll take a look at Batcher though.

Answer (score 1):

well you have to at least embrace X and Y with single quotes, I'd say.