# Run script with EntityManager JPA on Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, spring

I'm trying to run a script (.sql file) but i have multiples errors since i tried many ways, here's my main sql script:

```
INSERT INTO `Unity` VALUES (11,'paq',0,'2013-04-15 11:41:37','Admin','Paquete','Paq',0,'2013-04-15 11:41:37','AAA010101AAA',NULL);
INSERT INTO `product` VALUES (11,'chi','USD','chi one',0,'2013-04-15 11:42:13',0,'Admin','Chi name',0.25,0,15,'2013-04-15 11:42:13','AAA010101AAA',NULL);
```

and here's my main dao code:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
@Override
public Integer runSql(String path) {
    try {
        Archivo archivo = new Archivo();
        String strQuery = archivo.readFileText(path);
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(strQuery);
        return query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0; //TODO return false;
    }
}
```

If i run the script with only one Insert it runs ok, but when my script has more than 1 insert i get the following Exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `producto_servicio` VALUES (11,'chi','USD','chi
>   one',0,'2013-04-15 11:42:13',0,'' at line 2

Is there a way to run a script file with multiple inserts?

I also tried with BEGIN, and END, and START TRANSACTION AND COMMIT, but with no good results.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I don't think you can do it with entityManager, you will need to use the JDBC api directly. Similar question -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734423/executing-multiple-native-queries-in-one-go.

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute the script by the `em.createNativeQuery`, as i know. 
You should to split the script into statements and execute them one by one.

You may use [`ScriptRunner`](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/dev/com/ibatis/common/jdbc/ScriptRunner.html). It can be used separately from the MyBatis.

Example:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Connection connection = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(connection);
sr.runScript(new StringReader("INSERT INTO `Unity` VALUES (11,'paq',0,'2013-04-15 11:41:37','Admin','Paquete','Paq',0,'2013-04-15 11:41:37','AAA010101AAA',NULL);\r\nINSERT INTO `product` VALUES (11,'chi','USD','chi one',0,'2013-04-15 11:42:13',0,'Admin','Chi name',0.25,0,15,'2013-04-15 11:42:13','AAA010101AAA',NULL);"));
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks... by now what i did is read each line and execute it alone, each script should not be more than 5 querys, so by now ill take this solution, ill check later for the myBatis one, thanks

Comment: Is it possible to run JPQL scripts with this? Or is the scriptRunner always native sql only?