# How to execute .sql script file in Hibernate JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to perform bulk insert i have a .sql script file generated by reading excel file. Now i need to execute the script . How to do this in hibernate JPA ?

Comment: See this answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826524/run-script-with-entitymanager-jpa-on-mysql

Comment: Why do you want to use JPA for plain database stuff and thus not use any beneficial feature of JPA? This is better suited for JDBC and a bit of regular Java file/IO.

Comment: I already have Hibernate ORM which deals with the other process. So if i am going to use plain JDBC to run script then i need to get the JDBC connection for executing script.