# Creating multiple databases or schemas with Spring JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring, dao, spring-jdbc

i'm currently working on a Spring MVC project where i need multiple databases, one for each person that signs up(i know it's gonna be heavy but the number is limited).
So after a person logs in, he should have access only to his database, but how do i do that with Spring-JDBC ? ( i'm also using Spring Security for authentification) and how do i create a database after registration ? Using JDBC Template or something else  ?

PS : I was working with Spring JPA Hibernate and was forced to change to Spring-JDBC because i couldn't find a way to do this that way.

Comment: Please explain why you need a separate _database_ per registered user. The usual way to maintain user specific data is to segregate data within one set of tables based on a unique ID assigned to each user. In any case, your application must always be designed so that there is no way that a web site user can see the underlying database(s) anyway, for security reasons.

Comment: It's more like a private space for multiple entreprises, so for security reasons, and make things simpler, the multi database approach is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate supports this approach out of the box. It's called multi-tenancy. Check out the docs here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

But on it's own this is not going to get you where you want to go.  You are most certainly going to need another database schema in addition to the per customer one to at the very least store the information about each customers database connection.

You may want this schema to make use of hibernate entities, in which you'll have another Session Factory, or you may just want to call it through a JDBC template.

Either way, the creation of a database schema in sql is a matter of a few statements. You just have to be sure that the credentials you log in with have the appropriate permissions In postgres it's something like this, I'm sure it's similar in mysql:

```
CREATE USER circl WITH PASSWORD 'circl';
CREATE DATABASE circl;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE circl_test to circl;
```

You can run a script that looks like this in the spring jdbc template. Spring has a utility class that will do this for you as long as you don't expect a results set back: **org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils**.

Or you can even do it through JPA, following the instructions here:

[How can I execute a native SQL script in JPA/Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't offer the possibility to create a database with code, or does it ?

Comment: If you can execute a Sql statement you can create a database. You are going to probably need a  master schema to hold all your user database info. The user who owns that schema just needs the rights to create additional databases. In postres it's three lines of Sql. Create the database. Create the user. Grant the user permissions on the database. Store the users connection info in the matter schema and let Hibernate take care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you !  I'll try this. But i didn't really find a way with spring jpa hibernate in order to write and execute and sql statement. I would really appreciate it if you had an example.

Comment: I will pretty up the answer, but you'll want another session factory for your master schema, and maybe even some entities for managing your users. Follow the instructions here for executing a raw Sql script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: Here is the the approach for mysql: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826524/run-script-with-entitymanager-jpa-on-mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77013/discussion-between-robert-moskal-and-zouazou).